# Regular Expression Pattern Matching to HTML content

Tags: html, regex, vba

I am trying to do a Regular Expression search on string assigned to the HTML content of web search. The pattern I am trying to match has the following format `HQ 12345` the second fragment could also start with a letter so `HQ A12345` is also a possibility. As shown in the code below the regex pattern I am using is `"HQ .*[0-9]"`.

Problem is when i run the regex search the pattern matched is not just `HQ 959693` but also includes the rest of the html file content as shown in the snapshot of the message box below. [image: RegEx Pattern Matched]

```
Sub Test()
   Dim mystring As String
   mystring = getHTMLData("loratadine")
   Dim rx As New RegExp
   rx.IgnoreCase = True
   rx.MultiLine = False
   rx.Global = True
   rx.Pattern = "HQ .*[0-9]"
   Dim mtch As Variant
   For Each mtch In rx.Execute(mystring)
      Debug.Print mtch
      MsgBox(mtch)
   Next
End Sub

Public Function getHTMLData (ByVal name As String) As String
   Dim XMLhttp: Set XMLhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
   XMLhttp.setTimeouts 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000
   XMLhttp.Open "GET", "http://rulings.cbp.gov/results.asp?qu=" & name & "&p=1", False
   XMLhttp.send

   If XMLhttp.Status = 200 Then
      getHTMLData = XMLhttp.responsetext
   Else
      getHTMLData = ""
   End If
End Function
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with VBA, but had the same problem in C++. I think the string in the message box is correct because your regex engine returns any string which contains(!) your regular expression. In C++ I had to tell the engine to return a string only if it exactly matches(!) the regular expression. In C++ most engines provide a property or function "exactMatch()" to do this. Maybe your VBA engine provides a similar functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `?` to specify non-greedy, otherwise the match will consume up until the last digit of the entire string. Also, you are only matching one digit occurrence. Add a `+` to specify "one or more" so it will match your goal:

```
HQ .*?[0-9]+
```

Alternatively, you can try to use a negated character class like so:

```
HQ [^0-9]*[0-9]+
```

Or you can even simplify it further:

```
HQ [^\d]*\d+
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex matching is by default greedy. Unfortunately I didn't manage to reproduce precisely your issue, but I am pretty sure it is because you a long string which is being matched by '.*' to a number at the end.

I find this link useful, see the explaination near the bottom about the greediness of *

http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/RegEx-QuickRef.htm

I suggest changing your Regex to:

```
HQ .*?[0-9]+
```

That will match the "HQ " and any number of characters, followed by any number of numeric characters. It will also consume the minimal amount in the ".*", because of the "?".

Please respond if this does not work and I will getting your Regex running in Excel.

Comment: Thanks for your response. You are absolutely right the issue is the string being long.